# Can't pull out navigation drawer in Android Studio (Flamingo/Dolphin) anymore

Tags: android-emulator, navigation-drawer, android-studio-dolphin

New laptop, so started fresh with flamingo, noticed that I can't use the navigation drawer on the emulator anymore.
When I try to pull the drawer from (either) side, I get a chevron marker and it seems to jump to another activty.

[image]